# Unexpected behaviour when reading buffer in gpu land (wgsl)

Tags: rust, bevy, wgpu-rs, wgsl

Using the bevy engine I have made an octree that I am serialising and writing to a buffer:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Octree {
    pub root: [u32; 3],
    pub width: u32,
    pub leaves: Vec<Leaf>,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Leaf {
    voxel: OctreeVoxel,
    children: [u32; 8],
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct OctreeVoxel {
    pub id: u32,
    pub color: [u32; 3],
}
```

I am creating a buffer like this:

```rust
render_device.create_buffer(&wgpu::BufferDescriptor {
    label: None,
    size: 9000000,
    usage: wgpu::BufferUsages::STORAGE
        | wgpu::BufferUsages::COPY_SRC
        | wgpu::BufferUsages::COPY_DST,
    mapped_at_creation: false,
})
```

I am using bincode to serialise the data `bincode::serialize(&octree).unwrap()`
and writing to the buffer like this `render_queue.write_buffer(&buffer, 0, data);`

Here I am reading the data in gpu land:

```
let vox_photon = vec3<u32>(128 + 5, 128 + 5, 128 + 5);

var root = octree.root;
var width = octree.width;
var node = octree.leaves[0];
var next_index = 0u;
var exit = 0u;
while next_index != U32MAX && exit < 100 {
    let i = get_leaf(root, vox_photon);

    node = octree.leaves[next_index];
    next_index = node.children[i];

    root = get_new_root(i, root, width);
    width = width / 2u;
    exit += 1u;
}
if node.voxel.id != 0u {
    let color = node.voxel.color;
    return vec4<f32>(f32(color[0]), f32(color[1]), f32(color[2]), 255.0);
}
```

The unexpected behaviour is that the voxel id of the node it ends up with is `u32::MAX` while it should be `3`, and the colour should be `0,255,0`, but is `255,0,0`

So to me it seems like there is some shift in the data?
I am quite clueless as to what could cause that or how to fix it.

Comment: I feel like there's some missing context. But I want to mention, that `bincode` will write the length to `buffer` before the actual data. However it doesn't always do that, it does it in the case where the size of the type is "unknown". In short `f32` will be written directly to `buffer`, but `Vec<f32>` will first write `vec.len()` and then write the data

Comment: yeah i also asked this question else where and the answer there was that bincode does not encode the data in any way the gpu can understand. so id need to use something else. they mentioned bytemuck and bevy's buffer abstractions. But have not gotten it to work just yet

Comment: Yeah exactly. Since GPU just reinterprets the same data, whereas bincode is serializing it

Answer (score 0):

bincode was not serialising the data in a way the gpu can understand, this was the problem.

the way im doing things now that works is:

```
fn update_leaves_buffer(render_queue: RenderQueue, buffer: Buffer, octree: octree_v3::Octree) {
    let now = Instant::now();

    let mut byte_buffer = Vec::new();
    let mut temp_buffer = StorageBuffer::new(&mut byte_buffer);
    temp_buffer.write(&octree.leaves).unwrap();
    render_queue.write_buffer(&buffer, 0, &temp_buffer.into_inner());
    
let elapsed = now.elapsed().as_millis();
    if elapsed > 5 {
        info!("updating leaf buffer took: {}", elapsed)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should accept your own solution, so the question gets marked as answered :)

Comment: i know, just have to wait a day before i can do so :)